# Using neo4j DISTINCT and ORDER BY on different properties

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

I am trying to run the following cypher query on neo4j version 1.9M02

```
START me=node(2)
            MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends
            ,friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->products
            ,me-[r?]->products
            WHERE r is null
            RETURN products._id
            ORDER BY fr.CreatedOn DESC
            SKIP 0
            LIMIT 10
```

I expect to get all products that are ADDED or STOCKED by my friends which are not ADDED or STOCKED by me, ordered by the relation creation time. This query returns correct results but has duplicate products._id values (One user ADDED the product and other user STOCKED it). But I need only one instance of this products._id so I tried

```
START me=node(2)
            MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends
            ,friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->products
            ,me-[r?]->products
            WHERE r is null
            RETURN DISTINCT products._id
            ORDER BY fr.CreatedOn DESC
            SKIP 0
            LIMIT 10
```

(Added the DISTINCT for products._id) But this time I got **`Unknown identifier fr`** error. So I added fr to RETURN statement

```
START me=node(2)
            MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends
            ,friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->products
            ,me-[r?]->products
            WHERE r is null
            RETURN DISTINCT products._id,fr
            ORDER BY fr.CreatedOn DESC
            SKIP 0
            LIMIT 10
```

This query works without any error but returns duplicate product ids as before.

I've been only playing with neo4j for last couple of days, so not expert at all. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Hi there, got a case with console.neo4j.org so we can have an example and fiddle around?

Comment: Hi Peter, unfortunately I don't have any example. And I guess it will take ages for me to import my database to console.neo4j. One question, will there be any security issue if I publish my neo4j server here? It's not live data, only dev.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created a [***little case***](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=q5asct) with console.neo4j.org

With the following query, I get back `[4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3 ,2]`:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends
,friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->products
,me-[r?]->products 
WHERE r is null 
with distinct products._id as id, fr.CreatedOn as CreatedOn 
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC 
RETURN id
```

Putting distinct on the last line, and I get back `[3, 4, 2]`:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends
,friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->products
,me-[r?]->products 
WHERE r is null 
with distinct products._id as id, fr.CreatedOn as CreatedOn 
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC 
RETURN distinct id
```

It looks like the ordering gets lost with distinct.

**EDIT**

After filing [an issue on github](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/396) on this, it did dot take long before I got an [answer](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/396#issuecomment-11776149).

The suggestion in the answer was to run this query:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->product, 
WHERE not(me-->product)
RETURN product._id as id, min(fr.CreatedOn) as CreatedOn 
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

I modified the query so that it only returns the ids:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->product 
WHERE not(me-->product) 
WITH product._id as id, min(fr.CreatedOn) as CreatedOn 
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC 
RETURN id
```

And voila, it returns `[4, 3, 2]`!  (I have also created an [updated test case](http://console.neo4j.org/r/u866bj).)

Comment: Thank you very much for creating the case! It seems ORDER BY is ignored. If I change the the DESC to ASC, I still ge the same result.

Comment: Yes, please do file an issue, with the console example provided, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By using the aggregate function MIN, you can extract the earliest CreatedOn date. Once you have that, simple order the result set by the earliest date, like this:

```
START me=node(1) 
MATCH me-[:FOLLOWS]->friends-[fr:ADDED|STOCKS]->product, 
WHERE not(me-->product)
RETURN product._id as id, min(fr.CreatedOn) as CreatedOn 
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

Hth,

Andrés